# disable backface culling for imported .obj file three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, .obj, wireframe

I am having difficulty turning off wire frame rendering at the backside of my car.

How do you turn off backface culling in wire frame mode for three.js ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P07lt.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
{side: THREE.DoubleSide}
```

when defining your materials as seen in the [Materials documentation of three.js.](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Materials)